# How to convert an object or any type from observable which returns an array of objects to an array of objects..?

Tags: javascript, typescript, spring-boot, angular8

I Need to manipulate an array to get the data that i wanted, the flow is , Backend java returns an array of objects, angular gets the data and return as an observable from a service. Then subscribing to the observable method and looping through the data.

I have an interface structure same as the one from java object, looping through the data and push the values to an empty array of that interface type.

The problem here is logging of data gives a correct array output but when i use any array methods on the data it shows undefined.

```
this.service.getByd(d).subscribe(dataList => {

    for (let key in dataList) {
      if (dataList.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        this.event.push(dataList[key]);
      }
    }
  },
  err => {
    console.log(err);
  });

console.log(event) //expected output
console.log(event[0].eventType) //undefined
```

Comment: "use any array methods on the data" - where, Java, JavaScript, a method signature, just the code you posted?  Please add clarification if the duplicate that has been suggested does not satisfy with explicit details why not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing undefined because the code doesn't execute line by line:

```
dataList: DataList[] = new Array<DataList>();
function GetDataList(){

this.service.getByd(d).subscribe(dataList => {

... //populate array
  },
  err => {
    console.log(err);
  });

console.log(event) //This works because you are creating it before the get request
console.log(event[0].eventType) //This will get called before the subscribe finishes
}
```

I made some notes for how it works.

Additionally, if the Interface is a mirror of the backend, then you don't need to loop through it; just do this:

```
this.service.getByd(d).subscribe(dataList => {    
    dataList = dataList;
    console.log(dataList[0].eventType;
    }
  },
  err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```